# Nest.js Database Interoperability Questions

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

The question may seem voluminous - but in order to understand the essence in a different way, it seems extremely difficult to formulate it.
While reading the documentation and some other sources, I encountered a certain misunderstanding related to the variety of file types for interaction when working with the database:

```
.dao
.dto
.entity
.repo
```

Question:
How do these types of files differ conceptually in terms of functionality?
(If anyone has a detailed video or article on this topic, I will also be grateful for the link.)

There is also this microproject (working code) taken from the docks: 
https://github.com/Mike-Kharkov/nest-perfect-goods/tree/master/src

What should the code for entering values into the database look like?
(what should be the name of this file, where should it be located from the point of view of the approach, and what specific code should be written there?) 
For example, if I need to parse data (as I understand it from another service, it is correct to do this in this framework) and then put it in the database without a request via HTTP, then how to do it most correctly from the point of view of the approach?

P.S. I would be grateful for any constructive advice ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.dao`, `.repo`, and `.entity` are all pretty much the same thing. They're the ways that you define to talk with your database. There's a little give and take on the definition of the file, `.entity` is more of defining the table/entity in the database, but with something like `TypeORM` the entity becomes a method to talk to the database as well (either through the entity class or the `Repository` class).

DAO stands for `Data Access Object`, by the way, and you can read more about it and patterns around it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object).

`.dto` is for [Data Transfer Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) which is usually the definition of how data  is passed between services, or over the wire (incoming request, outgoing response, microservice body, etc). In NestJS we use DTO's for incoming request deserialization and validation, along with outgoing response serialization on occasion.